# Cypher: Returning all relationships between nodes in a collection

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm very simply trying to have Cypher output all relationships between nodes in a collection, or between matched nodes.

I've read several solutions to the problem on SO however none of them have worked for me.

```
MATCH (p:Paper {paper_id: '29912657'})
CALL algo.pageRank.stream(null, null, {direction: "BOTH", 
sourceNodes: [p]})
YIELD nodeId, score
WITH p, nodeId, score ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 25

MATCH (n)
WHERE id(n) = nodeId
WITH n, score, collect(n) AS c
MATCH (n)-[r:Cites]->(m)
WHERE m in c
RETURN r
```

In the first block of code I'm running personalized page rank over a node with a particular 'paper_id' property. I then order the results by score and take the top 25 results.

I've tried many variations of the second code block with no success. I'm trying to `MATCH` all relationships that exist between nodes in the collection `c` and `RETURN` them. When I run this I get an empty response. I suspect something is wrong with the `MATCH (n)-[r:Cites]->(m)` line, since if I try to `RETURN` other variables such as `n`, I still get an empty response. Removing that line and `RETURN`ing `n` will yield the top 24 scoring nodes in addition to the query node `p`.

If I try `OPTIONAL MATCH` instead of `MATCH` I get a list of 25 `null` values.

I'm using Neo4j version 3.4.5.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the right idea, collecting and then matching out to nodes in the collection, but you're running into issues with aggregation.

When aggregating, the non-aggregation variables become the grouping key, the context for the aggregation.

Looking at this line:

`WITH n, score, collect(n) AS c`

what this is asking is, per each `n` and `score`, give me the collection of that single `n`. You'll have a row per `n` and each of the collections will be single collections of that `n`.

In order to have the full collection of nodes, yet keep the single node per row, you'll need to collect first then unwind back to rows (we can omit the score here since you're never using it in the second part of the query.

```
... // since you already have the nodes you want no need to re-match to them
WITH collect(p) as nodes
UNWIND nodes as p  // let's just keep the variable consistent here
// we now have each `p` and the full collection of nodes
MATCH (p)-[r:Cites]->(m)
WHERE m in nodes
RETURN r
```

Comment: Beautiful, thanks for the help. I didn't realize the mistake I was making with the aggregation, this clears it up.